# Javascript and HTML, no output of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really new to HTML and Javascript, so forgive me for any obvious errors.

I am trying to get a Javascript function to work and return a value in HTML.

The function takes input of a number and returns a Roman numeral.

The only thing that happens is that a black '>' character is displayed, also ignoring my `<style>` declarations of it being #839496.

My code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Numbers</title>
    <style>
    body {background-color:#002b36}
         h1   {color:#fdf6e3}
         h2   {color:#fdf6e3} {font-size: size 9}
         h3   {color:#fdf6e3} {font-size: size 19}
         p    {color:#839496}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Numbers</h1>
    <h2>An app to display detailed info about a number</h2>
    <hr>
    <br />

    <form id="form">
    <input id="num" type="number" min="1" name="num">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML =  result;">Get results</button>
    </form>

    <h3>Results</h3>
    <hr>
    <p id="rom"></p>

    <script javascript type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("num").value = num;
    num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);

    var result = '',
        ref = ['M','CM','D','CD','C','XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I'],
        xis = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];

    if (num <= 3999999 && num >= 4000) {
        num += ''; // need to convert to string for .substring()
        result = '<label style="text-decoration: overline;">'+convert(num.substring(0,num.length-3))+'</label>';
        num = num.substring(num.length-3);
    }

    for (x = 0; x < ref.length; x++){
        while(num >= xis[x]){
            result += ref[x];
            num -= xis[x];
        }
    }

document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML = (result);

</script javascript type="text/javascript">


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `</script javascript type="text/javascript">`

Comment: also what is `h2   {color:#fdf6e3} {font-size: size 9}`

Comment: replace double quotes from single quote  within the **onclick** event  convert  this **<button onclick="document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML =  result;">Get results</button>**   to **<button onclick="document.getElementById('rom').innerHTML =  result;">Get results</button>**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only read the value of textbox `num` when the page is loaded. So you will never get the value when the user makes a change. You need to change your code so it lives inside of a function. When you click the button, it calls the function which runs the code with the updated values.

Second issue is the fact you have double quotes inside of double quotes. So the inside set closes off the outside. You need to use single quotes inside of them. Better yet add the event unobtrusively.

The `javascript` in the script tags makes no sense, get rid of it. `<script type="text/javascript">`
Also `</script javascript type="text/javascript">` is wrong. Get rid of the type, the closing tag should not have attributes. And you have an extra `</script>` tag.

You use `num` before you define it.

And styles do not separate everything into its own groups. And there is no "size" with setting the font. It should be like

```
h2 {
    color:#fdf6e3;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Numbers</title>
    <style>
      body {background-color: #002b36; }
      h1   { color:#fdf6e3; }
      h2   { color:#fdf6e3; font-size: 9px; }
      h3   { color:#fdf6e3; font-size: 9px; }
      p    { color:#839496; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Numbers</h1>
    <h2>An app to display detailed info about a number</h2>
    <hr>
    <br />

    <form id="form">
      <input id="num" type="number" min="1" name="num">
      <button onclick="calculate(); return false;">Get results</button>
    </form>

    <h3>Results</h3>
    <hr>
    <p id="rom"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function calculate () {
        num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);

        var result = '',
          ref = ['M','CM','D','CD','C','XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I'],
          xis = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];

        if (num <= 3999999 && num >= 4000) {
          num += ''; // need to convert to string for .substring()
          result = '<label style="text-decoration: overline;">'+convert(num.substring(0,num.length-3))+'</label>';
          num = num.substring(num.length-3);
        }

        for (x = 0; x < ref.length; x++){
          while(num >= xis[x]){
            result += ref[x];
            num -= xis[x];
          }
        }

        document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also helped me avoid any such mistakes in the future.

Comment: How can I reuse the input in another function?

Comment: reference the input? I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: No, say, I want to use another JS function which uses the input, do I just do a `num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);` or is it something else?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Numbers</title>
        <style>
        body {background-color:#002b36}
             h1   {color:#fdf6e3}
             h2   {color:#fdf6e3;font-size:9px}
             h3   {color:#fdf6e3;font-size:19px}
             p    {color:#839496}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Numbers</h1>
        <h2>An app to display detailed info about a number</h2>
        <hr>
        <br />

        <form id="form">
        <input id="num" type="number" min="1" name="num">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML =  result;">Get results</button>
        </form>

        <h3>Results</h3>
        <hr>
        <p id="rom"></p>

        <script>
        document.getElementById("num").value = num;
        num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);

        var result = '',
            ref = ['M','CM','D','CD','C','XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I'],
            xis = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];

        if (num <= 3999999 && num >= 4000) {
            num += ''; // need to convert to string for .substring()
            result = '<label style="text-decoration: overline;">'+convert(num.substring(0,num.length-3))+'</label>';
            num = num.substring(num.length-3);
        }

        for (x = 0; x < ref.length; x++){
            while(num >= xis[x]){
                result += ref[x];
                num -= xis[x];
            }
        }

       document.getElementById("rom").innerHTML = (result);

       </script>


  </body>
</html>
```